# Geometrical proofs for derivative rules

Tags: derivatives

Can the derivative rules be proven geometrically?

Consider the following graph:
[image]
y1 = x<sup>2</sup>

y2 = 4x<sup>2</sup>
the derivative of y1 and y2 is: $2x$ and $8x$ respectively.
If z = y1 + y2, then dy/dx = d(y1)/dx + d(y2)/dx;
This is actually the function 10x,

there are analytical proofs of the sum rule, product rule, quotient rule of derivatives. But, is there a geometrical proof of these rules? Particularly of the sum, quotient and the product rules of derivatives.

Comment: The derivative of y2 isn't 10x... it's 4*2*x = 8x

Comment: @JuanIgnacioCuiule, yes it's 8x but that added to 2x is 10x

Comment: @JuanIgnacioCuiule, I had mentioned it above. ;-)

Comment: "the derivative of y1 and y2 is: 2x and 10x respectively."
you wrote this...

Comment: @JuanIgnacioCuiule, thanks for the edit, didn't spot the typo.